# Remix IDE + Ganache vs Truffle + Ganache

Tags: truffle, remix, ganache

I have an issue migrating a smart contract from Truffle into `Ganache`. However, when I run the same smart contract from `Remix` IDE via `MetaMask` into `Ganache`, everything works fine.

To bypass the migrating error, I was thinking of using the Remix IDE ABI.js file instead of the `Contract.json` file that Truffle compiles. However, I am getting an error:

> Contract has not been deployed to the detected network
>   (network/artifact) mismatch.

I can't understand why does the contract work when deploying form Remix and interacting with it in Remix, and it doesn't when I use the ABI generated by Remix in my Web3js functions?

**UPD:** This is the React Component (based on Truffle React boilerplate) that I'm trying to work with. Here, ContractOne.json is the one that is generated by `truffle compile`. Had the truffle migration worked correctly, this would have worked.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ContractOne from "../../../build/contracts/ContractOne.json";
import getWeb3 from "../../utils/getWeb3";

export class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      web3: null,
      account: ""
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    getWeb3
      .then(results => {
        this.setState({
          web3: results.web3
        });
        this.getAccount();
      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.log("Error finding web3.");
      });
  }

  async getAccount() {
    const contract = require("truffle-contract");
    const contractone = contract(ContractOne);

    powerether.setProvider(this.state.web3.currentProvider);
    let instance = await contractone.at(
      "CONTRACT ADDRESS"
    );
    this.state.web3.eth.getAccounts((error, accounts) => {
      instance => {
      return this.setState({ account: accounts[0] });
      };
   });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="screen-one">
        <div className="h1">{this.state.account}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**truffle.js**

```
module.exports = {
  // See 
  // for more about customizing your Truffle configuration!
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually I don’t have issues with that, I deploy contracts via Remix and communicate from dapp via Truffle+Web3js. Even sometimes Truffle is not needed (e.g. no unit tests) then I use Web3js only.

1. Make sure you connect to the same network or emulator (with right network Id)
2. If you use Truffle, make sure, that you use Truffle artifact (compile contract via Truffle)
3. If you use Web3js, ABI of contract should be enough to instantiate contract

**UPDATE**
Truffle+Web3js

```
import contract from 'truffle-contract';
import ContractOne from './../../build/contracts/ContractOne.json';

const contractOne = contract(ContractOne);
contractOne.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);

var instance = await contractOne.at(<address>);

var balance = await instance.getBalance(); // call functions ...
```

Comment: That's, actually, what I am doing. 1. deploying the contract to Ganache from Remix IDE, 2. compiling the contract in Truffle and using the artifatcs.json to instantiate the contract. However, in Truffle Console, when manually typing a function (ContractOne.deployed().then()....) I am getting that error.

Comment: you don't need to execute `deployed` function. you should have something like `var instance = await ContractOne.at(<address>);` I'll put an example in answer

Comment: Thank you for the example! I have provided the exact React component that I'm having troubles with. I am trying to incorporate your code into it, but it seems there's async function needed, which I can't understand how to incorporate. could you please have a look at the React component code?

Comment: didn't get the logic of `getAccount`, you want to get account, but at the same time instantiate contract and do not use instance of the contract. you can mark `getAccount` as `async`, but you need to have `await` inside

Comment: I managed to change the code according to yours, and when the component mounts, I am still getting: `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Contract has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact mismatch)`

Comment: could you update code above and share Truffle config?

Comment: Updated the post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84743/discussion-between-aquila-and-ruham).